# NOW Function is not working in my query

Tags: mysql

My NOW Function is not working the way I want it to. I just want to simply find dates that are past todays date.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `trade_show_inventory` 
       LEFT JOIN `trade_show_reserved` 
              ON `trade_show_inventory`.`id` = `trade_show_reserved`.`productid` 
WHERE  `trade_show_inventory`.`quantity` > 0 
        OR `trade_show_reserved`.`datereserved` 
           + INTERVAL 5 day <= '2013-03-31' 
           AND `trade_show_reserved`.`datereserved` > Now()
```

EDIT:

I changed my query to this and it still is not working. Still working away at it..

```
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `trade_show_inventory` LEFT JOIN `trade_show_reserved`
    ON `trade_show_inventory`.`ID` = `trade_show_reserved`.`ProductID`
    WHERE (`trade_show_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0)
    or (`trade_show_reserved`.`DateReserved` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '$setupStart' and
           `trade_show_reserved`.`DateReserved` > '2013-03-25')";
```

Comment: Remember that NOW() includes a time component, then come back with what "not working the way I want it to" means specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys on the timestamp with the now function.

Comment: What is the `datereserved + INTERVAL 5 day <= '2013-03-31'` supposed to do ?

Comment: It adds 5 days to the date found in my table (datereserved) and then says if that result is less or equal then what the user selected (e.g. '2013-03-31) then its true.

Comment: It's still not working with the date by itself in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `where` clause is parsing like:

```
WHERE (`trade_show_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0) or
      (`trade_show_reserved`.`DateReserved` + INTERVAL 5 DAY <= '2013-03-25' and
       `trade_show_reserved`.`DateReserved` > NOW()
      )
```

If the date is five days before 2013-03-25, then it can't be in the future (as of today at least).

Put parentheses around the `where` clauses to get the logic you intend.

Comment: @wowzuzz . . . Then the problem is probably the comparison between a time stmap and a date.  Change `now()` to `date(now())`.

Answer (score 0):

NOW() doesn't return a date... it's a complete timestamp:

```
mysql> select NOW();
+---------------------+
| NOW()               |
+---------------------+
| 2013-03-25 17:20:06 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Try wrapping the [DATE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) around it:

```
mysql> select DATE(NOW());
+-------------+
| DATE(NOW()) |
+-------------+
| 2013-03-25  |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` returns the current date & time.

You would perhaps want to use `DATE()` as it returns the date without time.

Answer (score 0):

The NOW() function uses timestamp, i think you should first convert it into a date format that you require.